# Manually create Windows Azure .cspkg and the .cscfg files on Mac/Linux

Tags: node.js, unix, azure

I'm planning on moving my node.js application over to be a Windows Azure Cloud Service. However unlike Azure Websites there is no git integration, and one must upload a ZIP containing both a `.cspkg` and `.cscfg` file.

For developers using Windows machines to deploy, they have cspack.exe to create these files, however *nix users seem to have nothing - and more importantly no documentation on WHAT these files should actually contain/look like.

I'm [assuming there is no tool for *nix](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2229753-create-a-cspack-exe-for-mac-osx), however can someone perhaps point me in the direction of the specification for these files - or a tutorial where someone has created them manually?

**Update:** To clarify, I'm doing node.js development.

**Update 2:** I've just found this project, that can be [used in conjunction with the node SDK](https://github.com/c9/azure-packager-node)

Many thanks,

Comment: Wow... still no solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I've finally found out that the fabulous people at Cloud9 have all the tools you could possibly need on [their GitHub account](https://github.com/c9).

- [azure-cmdlet-node](https://github.com/c9/azure-cmdlet-node)
- [azure-packager-node](https://github.com/c9/azure-packager-node)
- [azure-node-basepackage](https://github.com/c9/azure-node-basepackage)
- [azure-management-sdk-for-node](https://github.com/c9/azure-management-sdk-for-node)

Comment: None of these projects work anymore: https://github.com/c9/azure-cmdlet-node/issues/4

Comment: They even deleted the projects :( Starting a windows vm only for this, it hurts

Answer (score -2):

The key here to understand is that if you are using Linux/Mac for Windows Azure Cloud Service development, you must not be using .net instead you might be using Java, PHP, Python or node.js, this almost cover 99% of Non windows development on Mac and Linux and there are SDK available for each of above language on Mac and Linux. These SDK does use language specific tools to  build the CSPKG file which you can deploy direct to Windows Azure or move to other machines and deploy from there.

If you visit each of below language specific link you will find a Link to Mac and Linux SDK which you can download to your specific machine and use it.

1. [Java SDK for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/)
2. [Python SDK for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/)
3. [PHP SDK for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/)
4. [Node.js SDK for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/)

[Here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253472&clcid=0x409) is the direct link to Windows Azure SDK for Node.js on Linux and [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/#Commands_to_manage_your_Azure_cloud_services) is the documentation link to use the sdk tools on Linux.

If none of above link help your language and platform specific request, please provide more info what you want to do using which tools and I sure can help you further.

Comment: Sorry yes I'm doing node.js development. And I've installed the sdk with `npm install azure` - however there is no command for generating CSPKG files.